# Is $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Determine whether the following sentence is correct or not.

$$ \mathbb{Z}_7^* \text{ is cyclic. }$$

Is $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ the same as $\mathbb{Z}$ without $0$??

If it is $\mathbb{Z}_7^*=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, how can it be a group when it does not contain $0$, the identity element??

Or does $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ mean something else??

Comment: You do not have handy a reference containing the definition of $\mathbb Z_7^*$?

Comment: I assume that you don't mean $\mathbb{Z}_7$ (the ring of $7$-adic intgers), but rather $\mathbb{Z}/7$ (the ring of integers modulo $7$). Many people denote $\mathbb{Z}/p$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for no particular reason - maybe they like notation disasters.

Comment: If you mean to ask about notation, then the title is very misleading. If that's the case, N.S.'s answer is correct: in general, if $R$ (like ${\bf Z}_7$) is a ring, then $R^*$ is the group of units of $R$. If $R$ is a field (like ${\bf Z}_7$), then this happens to be equal to $R\setminus \{0\}$. If you're asking about what's in title, then this is a duplicate (and quite trivial actually! just check the definition...).

Comment: No. $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the ring of $p$-adic integers) is the completion of the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ at its maximal ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that In given $G$ we have: $1^{-1}=1$; $2^{-1}=4$; $3^{-1}=5$; $6^{-1}=6$. Now use that in a group $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have same order to conclude that $2$, $4$ have order 3 and $3$, $5$ have order $6$ and $6$ is self invertible element in $G$. More clearly

$$\langle 2 \rangle = \{2, 2^2, 2^3, \ldots \} = \{2, 4, 1  \} = \langle 4 \rangle$$

$$\langle 3 \rangle = \{3, 3^2, 3^3, \ldots \} = \{3, 2,6,4,5,1 \} = \langle 5 \rangle$$

$$\langle 6 \rangle= \{6, 6^2, 6^3, \ldots \} = \{6, 1 \}$$

Here note that we are working under multiplication $\text{mod $7$}$.

Comment: So, to check if the group is cyclic I have to find a generator, an element $g$, where the other elements can be written as $g^n, n<ord(G)$ and $g^{ord(G)}=1 \Rightarrow g^6=1$. Is this correct?? So, do I have to check if $3$ or $5$ generate the other elements??

Comment: Finding generator is same as finding an element whose order is equal to order of group.now see my answer.now does things make sense to you?

Comment: Therefore, the elements $3$ and $5$ are the generators, so the group is cyclic, right??

Comment: yes u got it..well done

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang

Answer (score 4):

$(\mathbb{Z}_7, +, \cdot)$ is a ring. $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ denotes the units of this ring. This becomes a group with respect to the multiplication.

Now, since we have multiplication, zero is not the identity element. Which is the identity of this group?

Comment: So, we have $\mathbb{Z}_7*=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, right?? The identity element is $1$.

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. Now calculate the multiplicative order of those elements, can you find one which has the right order?

Comment: Is the order of the group $6$?? So do I have to find an element $g$ such that $g^6=1$?? Is it $g=1$??

Comment: @MaryStar $1$ is identity element and in any group identity element has order 1

Comment: So do I have to find an element with order $6$??

Comment: @MaryStar The order of any element is a divisor of $6$. Thus the possible orders are $1,2,3$ and $6$. You know which element has element 1, so you have 5 possible choices. To make sure the order is 6 then, you just have to make sure the order is NOT 2 NOR 3.

Answer (score -1):

This is a group under multiplication.