# Why is $\langle 3 \rangle$ a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}_7^*, \cdot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

This link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/948857/883424) shows that $\langle 3 \rangle$ is a generator for the given group by brute force method, that is trial and error. I was curious as to how to justify this using the theorem.

According to the Corollary, Generators of $\mathbb{Z}_n$:

> An integer $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if
> and only if $\gcd(n, k) = 1$.

Using this we know that $5$ is a generator of the group since gcd($|\mathbb{Z}_7^*|, 5) = 1$. (here $|\mathbb{Z}_7^*| = 6$, i.e, order of the group)

Although gcd($|\mathbb{Z}_7^*|, 3) = 3$.

Where am I going wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Note that $n=7$ but $|\mathbb Z_7^*|=6$. Read that corollary carefully. It's only applicable for additive group. So $3$ is indeed a generator of $\mathbb Z_7$. Now is $3$ a generator of $\mathbb Z_7^*$?, You need to check this and the corollary doesn't help you with that.

Comment: $U(7)\cong C_6$ is a multiplicative group, consisting of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ under multiplication modulo $7$. $\Bbb Z_n$ is an additive group. The group $U(7)$ has $\phi(\phi(7))=2$ generators, namely $3$ and $5$.

Comment: You’re in the multiplicative group, not the additive group, of the integers mod $7$. The condition in the multiplicative group is different.

Comment: It is very easy to see that $3^3=-1$ in $\Bbb F_7$, so $3$ has order $6$. Same with $5^3=-1$. So $3$ and $5$ generate $U(7)=(\Bbb Z/7)^{\times}$. Here $\Bbb Z/7$ is a ring, and $U(7)$ is the group of units of this ring. So I don't really see "brute force method, that is trial and error".

Comment: The element $\bar{3}\in (\Z_7^*,\cdot)$ is not the same as $\bar{3}\in (\Z_6,+)$. There's an isomorphism $\Z_7^*\to \Z_6$ mapping $\bar{3}$ to a generator of $\Z_6$ ($1$ or $5$). But this does not mean the element $3\in \Z_6$ generates $Z_6$ (it does not).

Comment: The *multiplicative* form of your corollary is that if $C_n$ is a cyclic multiplicative group of order $n$ generated by $a,\,$ then $a^k$ generates $C_n\!\!\iff\! \gcd(k,n)=1\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confused the groups $$\langle \Bbb Z_n, +\rangle\tag1$$ and $$\langle \Bbb Z_n^\ast, \cdot\rangle\tag2$$

Often when we mention a group, we leave the group operation implicit, and often it isn't confusing. This time, it was confusing.

The theorem you cited about $\gcd(n,k)=1$ is about the *additive* groups of line $(1)$.  But your post you linked to is finding a generator of one of the *multiplicative* group mentioned in line $(2)$.

As you observed, in this example, the group of interest, $\langle \Bbb Z_7^\ast, \cdot\rangle$, has *six* elements, not seven.

In fact $\langle \Bbb Z_7^\ast, \cdot\rangle$ and  $\langle \Bbb Z_6, +\rangle$ happen to be isomorphic.  But the isomorphism looks like this:

\begin{array}{c||cccccc}
\langle \Bbb Z_6, +\rangle
  & 0 & \color{darkgreen}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & \color{purple}5 \\
\langle \Bbb Z_7^\ast, \cdot\rangle
  & 1 & \color{darkgreen}3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & \color{purple}5 \\
\end{array}

As the theorem says, elements $1$ and $5$ are generators of $\langle \Bbb Z_6, +\rangle$.

But the corresponding generators of $\langle \Bbb Z_7^\ast, \cdot\rangle$ are called $3$  and $5$.

(There is a second isomorphism. Can you find it?)

For $\langle \Bbb Z_6, +\rangle$, it's easy to find generators ($1$ is always a generator) and your theorem tells us how.  But finding a generator of $\langle \Bbb Z_7^\ast, \cdot\rangle$  is not simple.

Comment: Ah thanks! That makes much more sense.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

A precise formulation of the cited statement is:

> Let $k,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n > 0$. The residue class of $k$ is a generator of the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ if and only if $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Clearly, your **multiplicative** group $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\},\;\cdot)$ does not match the structure required in the statement.

The group is cyclic of order $6$ though. So there must exist an isomorphism $\phi : (\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+) \to (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Hence you could apply the statement to $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+)$ and then use the isomorphism $\phi$ to translate the result to the group $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$. However, the problem is that you need an explicit isomorphism $\phi$ for the second step. Writing down such an isomorphism involves the knowledge of a generator of the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$, and you are back at your original problem...